# how can I detect a click on an element and all the elements inside except one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click on a div and trigger a function (in javascript/jquery) but dont triger it if I click a child element of that div.

Well, basically, I have this structure

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child_1">
      <div class="child_2">
         <button id="myButton"></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do, is that I want to detect if I click on `.parent` and triger a function, but dont triger it if i click on `#myButton`

so far, Ive tried many ways but I cannot figure out the proper way, if I have a

```
$(".parent").click(function(){...})
```

seems to call it as well if I click on myButton, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `event` target:

```
$(".parent").click(function(e){
    if (e.target.id == "myButton") return false;

    //code
})
```

Le fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rz6oqbh0/

Comment: thanks!! is there anyway to use that event on a $(document).on?

Comment: Yes, just pass it into the anonymous function `$(document).on("click", "elem", function(e) { e.target.id === });` @jpganz18

Comment: @jpganz18 -- No problem, mark the answer if ya can!